# The case of the vanishing tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just noticed an [old post](https://serverfault.com/questions/53954/centos-vs-ubuntu) to which I added the .`subjective` tag. That tag is no longer there and the edit history shows no changes made since, so whatever happened to the tag? Might this be a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 6):

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

> From this point on, meta-tagging is
>   **explicitly discouraged**.
>
> ...
>
> I’m pleased to announce that, as of
>   tonight, we have stormed the castle
>   gates and systematically eradicated
>   the most common meta-tags —
>   [beginner], [subjective], and
>   [best-practices] — from Stack
>   Overflow, Server Fault, and Super
>   User.

Comment: Haha beat you by 18 seconds. Your answer was better though.